# Why cant I convert to float

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to convert my CSV file into floats on certain ones that are numbers, However I keep getting ValueErrors.

```
def create_info(self, country_data):
    with open(country_data, "r") as csvfile:
      csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
      for words in csvreader:
    
        

        c = Country()

        c.country_name = words[2]
        c.country_code = words[3]
        c.acc_to_clean_fuel = float(words[4])
        c.acc_to_elec = float(words[5])
        c.annual_freshwater_withdrawl = float(words[6])
        c.armed_forces_tot = int(words[7])
        c.expense_gdp = float(words[8])

        self.__list_countries.append(c)
```

my CSV data is

```
Time,Time Code,Country Name,Country Code,Access to clean fuels and technologies for cooking (% of population) [EG.CFT.ACCS.ZS],Access to electricity (% of population) [EG.ELC.ACCS.ZS],"Annual freshwater withdrawals, total (% of internal resources) [ER.H2O.FWTL.ZS]","Armed forces personnel, total [MS.MIL.TOTL.P1]",Expense (% of GDP) [GC.XPN.TOTL.GD.ZS]
2018,YR2018,Argentina,ARG,99.8,99.9895782470703,12.9075342465753,105200,22.6877806247463
2018,YR2018,Australia,AUS,100,100,2.5254882398374,58100,26.2209281816529
2018,YR2018,"Bahamas, The",BHS,100,100,..,1300,17.4708838332366
2018,YR2018,Brazil,BRA,95.8,99.6999969482422,1.14131778837661,761500,35.453999893748
2018,YR2018,China,CHN,75.6,100,21.0387855949376,2695000,..
2018,YR2018,Cuba,CUB,93.5,99.5212097167969,18.2528856243442,76000,..
2018,YR2018,France,FRA,100,100,13.425,304800,46.7732066858883
2018,YR2018,Germany,DEU,100,100,22.8439252336449,181400,27.9229226403601
2018,YR2018,Greece,GRC,100,100,17.451724137931,147850,47.9372432955748
2018,YR2018,Ireland,IRL,100,100,2.91224489795918,8650,23.5797004719187
2018,YR2018,Italy,ITA,100,100,18.6551780821918,341500,42.5466717910759
2018,YR2018,Japan,JPN,100,100,18.3953488372093,261150,16.0811786865142
2018,YR2018,Malaysia,MYS,96.1,99.9922409057617,1.15637931034483,136000,15.9220539203293
2018,YR2018,Maldives,MDV,98.8,100,15.6666666666667,..,..
2018,YR2018,Mexico,MEX,84.8,99.5,21.721271393643,348000,20.4206535576881
2018,YR2018,Poland,POL,100,100,17.9067164179104,196700,33.3764400382599
2018,YR2018,Romania,ROU,87.1,100,15.1392166116092,126600,32.7748585957104
2018,YR2018,Saudi Arabia,SAU,100,100,974.166666666667,252000,29.0920814788993
2018,YR2018,United States,USA,100,100,15.7699117024308,1379800,22.3205732607659
2018,YR2018,United Kingdom,GBR,100,100,5.80620689655172,148450,37.4283979401227
,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
Data from database: World Development Indicators,,,,,,,,
Last Updated: 03/01/2023,,,,,,,,
```

value Error

```
File "main.py", line 7, in main
    Info.create_info("country_data.csv")
  File "/home/runner/Country-step-4/CountryIRSystem.py", line 26, in create_info
    c.acc_to_clean_fuel = float(words[4])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Access to clean fuels and technologies for cooking (% of population) [EG.CFT.ACCS.ZS]'
```

I tried to use split and strip but they were invalid in the strings

Comment: If you actually posted any of those `ValueErrors` then maybe we could even help you

Comment: We can't really help you without seeing the error but the problem is probably that you're not ignoring the header at the top with `Time,Time Code,...`

Comment: Also you have 5 lines of invalid data at the end of your CSV file.

Comment: I added the ValueError

Comment: The first line is a header row.  You have to tell the csv reader to skip that first line.

Comment: As a general principle just use a `Try, Except` block round the problem statement and print the value (words[4] in this case )causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help all. I wasn’t reading the Value error correctly and wasn’t skipping the first row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the first row of your CSV data are your headers -- and your loop is not taking that into consideration. So you're actually trying to convert your titles to floats.

If it's your only case for a CSV file and it's enough to skip the first line just in this instance, you can just add:

```
  csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  csvreader.__next__() # This will skip the titles
```

Before starting your loop and your conversions should work.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was reading the value error wrong. I thought it was telling me the values in that column couldn’t be read. I just disregarded that there was a header

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that it was trying to convert `'Access to clean fuels and technologies for cooking (% of population) [EG.CFT.ACCS.ZS]'` to float.  This is a value from the first line (presumably column names) which doesn't contain a number.  You should skip the first line.  You should also check for other invalid data conditions because, the last few lines in your sample contain empty columns and inconsistent data.